# Opencart. Функция getProductSpecials, модифировать запрос для вывода дополнительных товаров

Tags: php, sql, opencart, opencart2.0

Всем привет. Помогите разобраться.

**Дано:**

Имеется функция **getProductSpecials** в **catalog/model/catalog/product.php**
Используется для вывода товаров на странице с акциями.

**Задача:**

Необходимо дополнительно вывести на странице с акциями, товары, у которых поле **fake_special > 0** в **oc_product**

**Код оригинал**

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ps.product_id, (
SELECT AVG(rating) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 
WHERE r1.product_id = ps.product_id AND r1.status = '1' 
GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (ps.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE p.status = '1' 
AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' 
AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' 
AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) 
AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) 
GROUP BY ps.product_id";
```

Получилось частично решить вопрос, объединив два **SELECT** с помощью **UNION**, дополнительные товары вывелись.

```
$sql = "SELECT ps.product_id, (
SELECT AVG(rating) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 
WHERE r1.product_id = ps.product_id AND r1.status = '1' 
GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (ps.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE p.status = '1' 
AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' 
AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' 
AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) 
AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) 
GROUP BY ps.product_id
UNION
SELECT p.product_id, (
SELECT AVG(rating) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 
WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' 
GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE p.status = '1' 
AND p.fake_special > '0'
AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' 
GROUP BY p.product_id";
```

Но вылезла проблема с сортировкой, при **ORDER BY p.sort_order** например, вылезает ошибка **Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error: Table 'p' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list**

Не получается объединить оба **SELECT** под одним **ORDER BY**.

**UPDATE**
**Готовое решение**

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id, (
SELECT AVG(rating) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 
WHERE r1.product_id = ps.product_id AND r1.status = '1' 
GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps ON (ps.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE p.status = '1' 
AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
AND (ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' OR p.fake_special > '0')
AND (((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) 
AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) OR p.fake_special > '0') 
GROUP BY p.product_id";
```

Comment: *Но вылезла проблема с сортировкой, при ORDER BY p.sort_order например* В тексте запроса вообще нет такого поля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY`, в вашем случае, сортирует результирующую выборку двух `SELECT`, в которой нет `p.sort_order`. Такая запись сработает (у меня норм, mariadb):

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.sort_order as any_alias,
...
UNION
...
SELECT p.product_id, p.sort_order as any_alias,
...
ORDER BY any_alias
```

В любом случае `UNION` для этой задачи не нужен. Этот же набор данных можно достать через таблицу `product` (будет даже немного быстрее):

```
SELECT p.product_id, (
SELECT AVG(rating) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 
  WHERE r1.product_id = ps.product_id AND r1.status = '1' 
  GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps ON (ps.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE p.status = '1' 
AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' 
AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "'
AND (((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) 
AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) OR p.fake_special > '0')
```

Comment: Отлично. Пришлось подправить немного, теперь работает как надо. Обновил свой вопрос, вставил полностью готовое решение в конце.